# How to indicate with Microdata that a Schema.org 'Product' has no global identifier?

Tags: product, schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets, google-search-console

I have a warning in Google Search Console, that states "No global identifier provided (e.g. gtin, mpn, isbn)". Problem is that, my products do not have anything like this. Any idea on how to indicate Google that there is no such property? This is the only warning which prevents my products frorm being fully valid.

I am aware of [`identifier_exists`](https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/6324478?hl=en), but I cannot find any indications that it works with Microdata or how to specify it in Microdata. I cannot move to different format (JSON-LD), so that is not an option. Even if it was, I was not able to find how to specify it for JSON-LD as well.

I have specified `sku`, which is, as far as I understand, a valid identifier [according to Schema.org](https://schema.org/sku). I can validate, that Google is able to see it, but it still complains, that there is no identifier?

[image: No global identifier provided (e.g. gtin, mpn, isbn)]

Answer (score 2):

sku seems to be separated out with Google and does not resolve that warning.

I think you have to live with it. The warning is because having one of those identifiers helps Google work things out. Telling Google you can't provide it makes no difference, Google still does not have it.

It's similar to the reviews warning. You will get that if you have no product reviews. But it's not an error. All it really means is you can't get the review star rich result if you have no reviews.

It is not an error with your structured data. These warnings are specifically related to getting rich results in Google search.

It would be nice if those tools provided clearer messages.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Google's description of `mpn'](https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/6324482?hl=en), these don't have an inherent structure that needs to be followed, they just need to be unique for the same manufacturer. Also, the docs state:

> Use the MPN assigned by the manufacturer. Unless you’re the manufacturer, don’t use a value that you’ve created.

Since [I sell my own products](https://scalablemaps.com) (shameless plug) and I'm the manufacturer, I get to decide what `mpn` values to put there. What I did is to simply use the same value both for `sku` and `mpn` and I now I don't get this warning anymore.